# How to clear the contents of an Array in javascript by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, reset

I have a number of buttons that when clicked add a word to an array. This array is used in the url name to download a file:

```
 <button id="button9" onclick="myFunction7();"</button>

 <script>
 var a = []; 
 function myFunction7() { 
 a.push("h"); 
 }

 <button id="button10" onclick="myFunction8();"</button>

 <script>
 var b = []; 
 function myFunction8() { 
 b.push("h"); 
 } 


 var url = [a,b,c,d];
```

(I have just included two buttons, they also exist for c, d in same format)

The function for the buttons works and correct file is loaded. Is there a way to reset the url variable and empty the array? I would like to have a button that resets the url variable on my webpage so a new array can be created. I have created a button that refreshes the entire page but this is not ideal as each time my web page has to re load just to clear the array!

Comment: Do you want to clear the `url` array or the arrays `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`?

Comment: I would like to clear both the url and the a b c d

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To clear an array you only need to re-declare it as an empty array `url = []`

```js
var url = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
console.log(url) // added for example

function clearArray() {
  return url = []
}
function getArray() {
  return console.log(url)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clearArray(); alert('Array cleared. Now click getArray() button')">Clear Array</button>
<button onclick="getArray()">Get Array</button> <!-- click me after clearing the array -->
```

Comment: What does the getArray function do?

Comment: @Kar98k - For demonstration purposes only. I should have made that clear in the answer. Once you've cleared the array, clicking the *Get Array* `getArray()` button will clear the array and output it to the console log to verify that the `url` array has been cleared. Again, just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @cyberbit Thanks, I have tried this method and it is successfully removing the contents of the Array. However I am not trying to clear the array, I am trying to reset it. The a, b, c, d in the array are variables from the other buttons. Is it possible to instead of delete them just reset them?

Comment: @Kar98k By "reset" do you mean "reassign?" Basically set `url` back to `[a,b,c,d]`?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ideas and concepts regarding the question that I would like to discuss.

**Concept 1:**

In **ES6 (ECMAScript 2015)**, we mostly declare arrays and objects using a **const** keyword.

```
const url = ['a','b','c','d'];
```

In this case, if we directly try to clear an array using `url=[]` we'll get an error, which looks something like this.

> script.js:96 Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
>       at HTMLImageElement.flipcard (script.js:96)

Another method that we can We can use to clear the array contents is by using the **pop()** method that is available for every array.

```
while(url.length>0){
 url.pop();
}
```

**Concept 2:**

If we directly do `url=[]`, we are basically assigning an empty array to the same variable **url**, and the old array `['a','b','c','d']` is roaming somewhere in the **memory heap** but without any reference variable pointing to it. *As arrays are objects in javascript*, we don't consider it as a good practice to have objects pointing to nothing in our program. As this may lead to the concept called **MEMORY LEAKS** in our program.

**Note:** By using **pop()** method on the array we are basically changing the same array url itself, without re-assigning it and this way we also stop **Memory leaks.**

Below is the full js program about how to do it:

```js
var url = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
console.log(url) // added for example

function clearArray() {
  while(url.length>0){
    url.pop();
 }
  return url;
}
function getArray() {
  return console.log(url)
}

console.log("clearArray function return back an empty array :",clearArray());
```